# Is there a way to shape a button around its picture in Delphi

Tags: delphi, button, shapes

I am using a component called TAdvShapeButton from TMS software to create buttons around a circle.

[image]

This button works by adding pictures for; down, hot, disabled and normal states.
It preserves the transparency from the PNG EXCEPT if a TAdvShapeButton is above another TAdvShapeButton.

This has for effect the following problem because the button is rectangle.

[image]

Is there a way to change the shape of this button from a rectangle to match the picture it loaded?

I am guessing something like what is used for rounding off corners of a form:

```
procedure TfCompass.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  region:HRGN;
begin
  region := CreateRoundRectRgn(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top, ClientRect.right, ClientRect.bottom, 326, 326);
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, region, true);
end;
```

Not sure how to proceed.

Many thank.

Edit 1:

This problem occurs even if the TAdvShapeButtons are dropped on the form.

[image]

Comment: The most used way to preserve transparency is by drawing the parent canvas as the background then painting your own stuff on it (png, text.....), So the first place I would look is to see if the button is descendant of `TGraphicControl` or not if yes the first and quickest fix is to make it `TCustomControl` descendant so all buttons stop sharing the same drawing space even if they overlap.

Comment: Now as a User tilting my head a little to read the text would be annoying. if I where in your position I would change the shape of the buttons to circles and write the text horizontally with the buttons differing in color (even if only alternating by shades of the same background color) and as a bonus maybe make all this a single control.

Comment: TAdvCustomShapeButton = class(TCustomControl, IWinStyle, ITMSStyleEx)

Comment: I wanted to make them into circles but they ended up being too big and text too small..

Comment: is the blue Circle in the image above also `TAdvCustomShapeButton`?

Comment: Try removing the blue circle and see if the error stays. if yes then the blue circle is a `TWinCntrol` parent of `TCustomControl` and all of the buttons including the blue circle share the same parent (the gray area), try changing the blue control to `TGraphicControl` and see again

Comment: The blue circle is a Timage but it doesn't matter, the problem occurs even if I just drop the 2 TAdvShapeButton on a new form as per my edit above.

Comment: Changing the classes had no effect.

Comment: After seeing your edit I can say that what you are looking at is not an error nor bug it is an expected behavior from that Control. the button copy the same background witch is the white color.

Comment: Is there a way to shape the button according to the image within it at runtime?

Comment: I have never read or encountered a topic speaking about shaping the button client area to a shape other than the basic shapes (yours is not). However I think you could get away with what you are trying if you make a custom button like the one you have but instead it should descend from `TGraphicControl` . (and to have the same effect you have you only play on the Z-Order of your buttons)

Comment: The behavior is a bit strange. Did you try enabling double buffering for the form?

Comment: Yes I did. Its really to do with transparency. I've been trying other solutions like using timage instead of buttons etc but it interferes with other controls.

Comment: - *"Not sure how to proceed."* - Use the button's handle and client rectangle instead of the form's.

Comment: SetWindowRgn is for a window not a component.

Comment: A component can be a control or not, a control can be a window control or not. You [state that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159652/is-there-a-way-to-shape-a-button-around-its-picture-in-delphi#comment108198522_61159652) it is a TCustomControl descendant, which is a TWinControl descendant. That's a control with a window.

Answer (score 0):

Going off Sertac's recommendation I found the following code:http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=45051

```
procedure TForm1.MakeRounded(Control: TWinControl; iCorner : Integer);
var
  R: TRect;
  Rgn: HRGN;
begin
  with Control do
  begin
    R := ClientRect;
    rgn := CreateRoundRectRgn(R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom, iCorner, iCorner);
    Perform(EM_GETRECT, 0, lParam(@r));
    InflateRect(r, - 5, - 5);
    Perform(EM_SETRECTNP, 0, lParam(@r));
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, rgn, True);
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

Although I would have liked to find a way to create HRGN by using the png inside my ShapeButton, I found that rounding the corners prevented the overlapping.

Comment: "EM_..." are edit messages, I suspect middle 3 line in your code have no effect.